# simple Perl math while keeping a specific number of digits

Tags: perl, math

I'm trying to do some simple math like

```
$example = (12 - 4);
```

but I need single digit answers to have a 0 in front of them so $example should be

```
08 not 8
```

I know I could do something like

```
if ($example < 10){
    $result = "0$example";
}
```

But I have to think there's a way to specify how many digits you want your output to be when doing simple math like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend saving formatting like this until you print to screen. You can then use printf or sprintf to format the number how you want.

```
my $example = 12 - 4;
printf("%02d", $example);
```

Will print:

```
08
```

To save it in a string for later use sprintf:

```
my $example = 12 - 4;
$formatted = sprintf("%02d", $example);

print "$formatted\n";
```

If you need to fill decimal places use the following:

```
my $example = 12 - 4;
printf("%0.2f", $example);
```

will print:

```
8.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, sprintf does exactly what I needed!